# What is the right preposition: the film was dubbed in English or into English?

Tags: prepositions

`The film was dubbed in English` or `The film was dubbed into English`?
Merriam Webster [says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dub#dictionary-entry-2) that `in` is the right preposition here, but MW is the only dictionary I found with this opinion. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dub), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dub) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dub_1) shares the opinion that `into` is right.
On the other hand, I found several articles on Guardian and NY Times where `in` was used.
Which one is the right option and why? Thank you.

Comment: It seems that _dub in_ is the technical term for inserting a new soundtrack into a film, but as we speak of words being _translated into_ another language, it seems quite natural to say that a film was _dubbed into_ English. I don't think either is wrong.